# What determines how much Tribute you get from a Ritual encounter?

Tags: path-of-exile

In the Ritual league, you have to fight waves of enemies you previously killed around a special altar to receive tribute. Seems straightforward enough, but the amount of tribute I get from each encounter seems almost random. What affects this amount and can I influence it?

I know that the waves are formed from enemies killed around the altar before its activation. What I don't quite understand is whether it's all monsters killed at any point or just some. Is there a limit? Should I try to draw more enemies into the ritual area before knocking on the altar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw more in. There is no limit. There are methods to juice your rituals like the strongbox mod from the map device, scarabs such as breaches, legion, etc. Sextanting watchstones for more monsters also helps.

Basically just increase the amount of monster packs for the map in order to get more points.